# Can't connect to host machine to any port from docker container linux

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, firewall

i can't connect to my localhost mongodb from docker container.
I can get page nginx if run curl 172.17.0.1 or (host.docker.internal) inside docker container, but if i try use another port curl not outputs nothing. Any help?
On windows machine all works fine, but i noticed that there is another port for connect to host machine host.docker.internal = 192.168.65.2

I think maybe linux blocks ports for docker container?

System: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Docker: 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b

Docker file

```
# build step
# Base image
FROM node:18

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./

# Install app dependencies
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

# Creates a "dist" folder with the production build
RUN npm run build

# Start the server using the production build
CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

docker-compose file

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  api: 
    build: .
    container_name: api-container
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:${APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Comment: You should be able to reach port 27017 like you're able to reach port 80. But `curl` speaks HTTP. You can't connect to Mongo with it, because Mongo doesn't speak HTTP. You need to use a program that can talk to a Mongo database.

Comment: @HansKilian i use curl for check availability, because if curl sees the address, his write "It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.". First i tryed connect, then I already decided why there is no access to mongo.